# A call to PInvoke function ... has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Everytime I call the function mouse_event I get the error

> A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

```
const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);


switch (mouseAction)
        {
            case ENUMMouseAction.LEFTDOWN:
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ENUMMouseAction.LEFTUP:
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ENUMMouseAction.RIGHTDOWN:
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ENUMMouseAction.RIGHTUP:
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
        }
```

I have tried all available CallingConventions and none seems to work, Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

- The calling convention should be `Stdcall`.
- The parameter types are all wrong. The first four parameters are `uint` and the final parameter is `UIntPtr`.

You need to take care when reading the documentation. It can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will mark as answer as soon as I'm allowed. I was just pretty confused since it had worked in a previous project but I assume that was using .NET Framework version 3.5.

Comment: That code was always wrong. If it ever worked it was purely by chance.